# Django rest nested serializer fails

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My model relationships are: A 'Reader' will have a single 'Wishlist' and a 'Wishlist' will contain many 'Book's. I want to create an empty Wishlist automatically during Reader object instance creation.

My Models:

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    wishlist_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)        


class Reader(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    # A library has many readers
    which_library = models.ForeignKey('Library', related_name='readers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wishlist = models.OneToOneField(Wishlist, null=True, blank=True)


class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    which_wishlist = models.ForeignKey('Wishlist', related_name='my_wishlist', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

And serializer:

```
class ReaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email')
    password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password')

    class Meta:
        model = Reader
        #fields = '__all__'
        #depth = 1
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'address', 'dob', 'which_library', 'wishlist')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.user.email = validated_data.get('user.email', instance.user.email)
        instance.user.password = validated_data.get('user.password', instance.user.password)
        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
        instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
        instance.dob = validated_data.get('dob', instance.dob)
        instance.which_library = validated_data.get('which_library', instance.which_library)
        instance.wishlist = validated_data.get('wishlist', instance.wishlist)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        user.set_password(user_data['password'])
        user.save()
        wishlist_data = validated_data.pop('wishlist')
        reader = Reader.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Wishlist.objects.create(reader=reader, **wishlist_data)
        return reader
```

My view that handles the creation:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def reader(request, library_id):
    """
    List all readers in a specific library, or create a new

    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ...

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ReaderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am making a POST call to create a Reader with following JSON data:

```
{
    "username": "sample",
    "email": "sample@gmail.com",
    "password": "012345",
    "phone": "012345",
    "address": "sample address",
    "which_library": "2",
    "wishlist": []
}
```

Where it gives me following error:

```
{
    "wishlist": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list."
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would throw away the `Wishlist` model completely as it does not hold any data.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    reader = models.ManyToManyField('Reader', related_name='wishlist')
```

This should make the whole thing easier as you no longer need to create the wishlist automagically and I guess your problem will desolve in air.

If you need the Model (e.g. you expect data to arise later) you might use `through` on the `ManyToManyField`. Details can be found [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

**UPDATE**

I rethought the advise regarding the through model. This approach would not reflect your current state as it would have one entry per relation not per reader. Nevertheless I would recommend the simplification of your models as suggested above.

Comment: I liked your approach, it sounds rather logical than what I was thinking. Let me try this.

Comment: For this reader field it is giving me TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'. Is it not allowed?!

Comment: Sorry, my failure. I copy + pasted your `ForeignKeyField` and forgot to remove it. I've updated the answer to include this argument anymore.

Comment: Great! Would I need to change my ReaderSerializer? I am sending POST with ´{
    "username": "sample3",
    "email": "sample3@gmail.com",
    "password": "5647",
    "phone": "836365",
    "address": "sample3 address",
    "which_library": "1",
    "wishlist": []
}` but it fails saying 'wishlist' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Just don't handle the wishlist at all on creation. Make another detail route for readers like `/v1/readers/<int:pk>/wishlist/add` which accepts a book pk. Do the same for removal and use `/v1/readers/<int:pk>/wishlist/` to return the wishlist of books.

Comment: Okay! I will do so

Comment: Hi! Could you perhaps take a look at if you like?- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066863/django-rest-framework-many-to-many-field-create-view I couldn't really figure it out :(